# VP9 video codec - libvpx version

Tags: video-codecs, vp8, libvpx

Currently , I am using libvpx v1.0.0 for vp8. Can I use the same version for vp9 or do I need to change to v1.3.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.3.0 introduces vp9 support

See change log here

https://code.google.com/p/webm/source/browse/CHANGELOG?repo=libvpx

So the answer to your question is yes you need to use 1.3.0 if you want vp9 support